# C# MVC 5, como puedo poblar un modelo del negocio con datos repartidos en varios controladores.?

Tags: c#, mvc, poo, model

Tengo datos que llegan a varios controladores en mi home.
Para cada action en el index manejo modelos diferentes y entrego resultados a la vista dependiendo del modelo que use. También tengo información de validaciones y otras clases que debo insertar en la BD.
Todo está disperso entre clases de validaciones, de los controllers y helpers.

Ahora me toca cargar datos de una tabla con información a la BD desde para lo cual lo único que se me ocurre es crear el modelo (DatosDeArchivosModel) que voy a poblar llamandolo desde las diferentes partes y pasandole como parametro DatosDeArchivosModel.

por ejemplo:

```
private void PoblarModeloArchivos(DatosDeArchivosModel model)
{
FileModel.ByteFileType = model.ByteFileType;
FileModel.CommStatus = model.CommStatus == null ? 0 : model.CommStatus;
FileModel.CorrespondentNR = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CorrespondentNR) ? "" : model.CorrespondentNR;
FileModel.CtInfo = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CtInfo) ? "" : model.CtInfo;
}
```

Es correcto hacerlo de esta forma o existe alguna forma mas estandard de generar la informaciòn y pasarla al modelo DatosDeArchivosModel??

Answer (score 0):

En principio suena a que está mal diseñado el modelo de negocio, pero debido a que no especificas que tipo de datos recibes en los otros controladores, imagino que no se guardan en tu base de datos, para éste tipo de escenario utilizamos objetos de sessión: `HttpContext.Current.Session["datodecontroladorX"]=objecto.valor;`. Luego los recuperas con la misma forma: var misvalores=HttpContext.Current.Session["datodecontroladorX"] as string;Segundo si planeas llamar un método desde tu controlador home debes declararlo como public void y tu ModelViewModel verifica que esté mapeado a los datos que quieres devolver a la vista.Probablemente tengas que hacer un RedirectToAction("ActionName",modelo_a_enviar) en tus otros controllers.